# not getting this backbone router to work

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Trying to get the simplest backbone router to work to see if I like how it works. I am able to get models to work so I think it's loading correctly but when I access with http://localhost:3000/xxx#testindex, nothing happens.

**edit 1**
I thought there wasn't an error but now I'm getting `h is not a function`. Hmm... I am a little stumped.

What am I doing wrong? Thx

```
<html>
  <head>
   <script src='/assets/underscore.js'></script>
   <script src='/assets/backbone.js'></script>

  </head>
<body>
<script>
var PageRouter=Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes:{
    "testindex": "index"
  },
  index: function(){ alert("I am here in index")}
});

window.onload=function(){
 // alert("this loaded");
 var app_router = new PageRouter;
 Backbone.history.start();
}
</script>

<a href="#testindex">Activate route</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backbone depends on [jQuery or Zepto](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/):

> For RESTful persistence, **history support via Backbone.Router** and DOM manipulation with Backbone.View, include json2.js, and either jQuery ( > 1.4.2) or Zepto.

Emphasis mine. You forgot to include jQuery or Zepto and that's where your "h is not a function" error comes from. Since you'll probably be pulling in jQuery, you should use `$(function() { ... })` instead of the old school `window.onload`.

Once you sort that stuff out, it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/3XUxS/

Answer (score 0):

You might try assigning `root` when you call [`history.start`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#History-start):

```
Backbone.history.start({
  root: '/xxx'
});
```

Comment: (it's the only thing I immediately notice looking at your code)